# error in reading input using istringstream in C++

Tags: c++

I have to take input as below

```
3
10 20 30 40 50
60 70 80 90 10
20 30 40 50 60
```

so I have below code

```
class Student {

public:
    void input() {
        cin.ignore();
        string line;
        std::getline(std::cin, line);

        // build an istringstream with above received line as data source.
        std::istringstream iss{ line };
        // define vector Marks use range constructor and steam iterator
        unsigned int mark = 0;
        while (iss >> mark) {
            cout << "pushing mark " << mark << endl;
            m_vecMarks.push_back(mark);
        }
    }
private:
    vector< unsigned int > m_vecMarks;

};



int main() {
    int n; // number of students
    cin >> n;
    Student* s = new Student[n]; // an array of n students

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "Enter the input for " << i << endl;
        s[i].input();
    }
}
```

While running above code I am getting below output

```
pushing mark 0
pushing mark 20
pushing mark 30
pushing mark 40
pushing mark 50
pushing mark 0
pushing mark 70
pushing mark 80
pushing mark 90
pushing mark 10
pushing mark 0
pushing mark 30
pushing mark 40
pushing mark 50
pushing mark 60
```

I am not getting bug in my code what is causing my initial value of line is printing as 0 instead of correct value in my case it is 10 for example

Kindly help

Comment: You're showing the output you get, but what is the output you *want* to get? Have you tried to step through your code in a debugger to see when and where (if at all) it goes wrong?

Comment: As a hint though: Think a little bit more about what that call to [`ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) is doing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) already reads and ignores the newline. So you have the [`std::ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/ignore) in the "wrong " place.

You only want to discard the newline left in input by [`std::cin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin). So remove the `ignore` call in `input()` member function and instead add it right after `cin` call:

```
int n; // number of students
cin >> n;
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

(you'd need `<limits>` header.)